# issue using npm to install upper-case module on linuxmint OS

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, node-modules

`npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/spipl8/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/spipl8/package.json'
npm WARN spipl8 No description
npm WARN spipl8 No repository field.
npm WARN spipl8 No README data
npm WARN spipl8 No license field.`

this all error was occur when i try to install the upper-case modules of node.js NPM on linux mint please help me out to solve it.

Comment: They are warnings not `error`. Please check your `node_modules` directory for the module.

Comment: i got node_modules but how to use that upper-case module in my script
i use require('upper-case'); but still having same problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is not the issue with npm, the error is saying it cannot find package.json in your directory.

Comment: so how can i fix that problem .Guide me and help me out if you have any idea about this.

Comment: paste your package.json here